# Why 2 files downloaded by the same code of php are different?

Tags: php

There are 2 php files

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="GET")
{
    if(isset($_GET['testo']))
    {
        if(logged($_GET['testo']))
    {
        $filename = "Demon.zip";
        $filepath = 'uploads/' . $filename;
    
        if(!empty($filename)&& file_exists($filepath))
        {
           $demo_name = "Demon.zip";
           header('Content-type: application/zip');  
           header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$demo_name.'"');  
           readfile($demo_name); // auto download
        
            exit;
        
        }
        else
        {
            //comments
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //comments
    }
    }
    else
    {
        //comments
    }        
}
else
{
    //comments
}
```

From this file I can download from the server but the zip file I downloaded can't be unzipped by an applications.

```
<?php
           $demo_name = "Demon.zip";
           header('Content-type: application/zip');  
           header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$demo_name.'"');  
           readfile($demo_name); // auto download
?>
```

Instead this file can be downloaded and can be unzipped. I discovered that the size of the downloaded file from the first file is bigger than the another one... I don't know why, the download code is same!!! How can I solve this?

Comment: Your first script probably produced output before this already. (Output buffering would have to be enable then, so that the `header` calls don't causes errors.)

Comment: `I discovered that the size of the downloaded file from the first file is bigger than the another one`...open the files in a text editor such as notepad++ and compare them. Probably one of them contains something which wasn't supposed to be there. As CBroe says, probably it was put there accidentally by your PHP code.

Comment: There is the html before the downloaded file... How can I remove that?

Comment: @7ZeroDawn Probably you have this HTML code in your PHP Script not....?

Comment: Remove the code which generates the HTML (or if it's static HTML, remove that - or at least put PHP code around it to ensure it doesn't get output when the file download action is taking place. Ideally, you'd have separation between code which outputs HTML for consumption on the page, and code which downloads files...putting that in the same script is a recipe for the sort of slip-up which seems to have occurred here).

Comment: I moved the html part to another page, and the download to another and now works! Thank you all!! ^^

Comment: @7ZeroDawn In this case, you may like the comments that helped you solve your problem. Comments that added something useful to your post. :)